# How to add in Windows CE foreign language support?

Tags: windows-ce, regional-settings

How to add in Windows CE foreign language support? Computer - netbook.

Comment: Wanna change the whole OS language to Russian? and which version of Windows CE?

Comment: version: 5.0 (build 1400), i want to change User Interface Language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add a foreign language by using the Region & Language application in the Control Panel. However, [this article](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/WindowsCE/microsoft.public.windowsce.app.development/2008-01/msg00040.html) states that it's up to the device OEM to decide what, if any, alternative languages are allowed in his operating system.